# Prove that the modulus of a complex number defines a field norm on $\mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a question on a past exam paper i am struggling to answer.

Here is it:

**Prove that the modulus of complex numbers defines a field norm on $\mathbb C$**

Hence, $|z|$ is a measure of the "size" of a complex number z.

So i know that first i must prove that for any $z$, $z_1$,$z_2$ 
$\in \mathbb C$,

$-|z| \le Re(z)$,

$Im(z) \le |z|$ and $|z_1 \overline z_2|=|z_1||\overline z_2| $

But i am a bit confused about how to go about this.

Any help appreciated

Many thanks

Comment: If $z = x+iy$, $|z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. Further, squares of real numbers are non-negative

Comment: sorry i should have put this in my question, i know this already but i am still struggling to answer this

Answer (score 0):

The field norm of a complex number $z$ can be defined informally as the distance of the vector emanating from the origin. The modulus is defined as the radius of this vector. This radius = $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r$. We can get a better appreciation of where this euclidean distance for determining the radius or quote on quote "modulus of a complex number $z$" is evaluated (by the Pythagorean theorem).

[image]

Comment: thanks, i know this but i dont get how the modulus defines a field norm on C... a bit confused to be honest